# Delete rows based on comparing cells to user entered date and skipping blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to remove rows based on the termination date of an employee. I don't want blank cells to be deleted because those employees are still active. I have a text box that pops up and asks for the dates and then show the entered date. Then it is supposed to search column G for any dates prior to the entered date and delete those rows, skipping any row that is blank. 
I have been searching everywhere for a way to do this but I can't get the Macro to stop deleting every row but the headers. The dates are in column G and it's about 46 rows but that can change.

```
Sub DateSelectandClean()
    '
    ' DateSelectandClean Macro
    ' User enters date and spreadsheet deletes everything prior to that date, ignoring empty cells.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim W2Year As Date, N As Long
Dim dt As Date

W2Year = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter W2 Year as xx/xx/xxxx Date:", Type:=2))
MsgBox W2Year


N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row


For i = N To 2 Step -1
dt = Cells(i, 1).Value
    If (Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And dt < W2Year) Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOgZG.jpg)

Comment: If the dates are in column G (or `7`), wouldn't you want to do `Cells(i,7)`? not `1` (which is column  A)?

Comment: do you have a column that always have a value?

Comment: @BruceWayne - I've tried that but I will try it again.

Comment: @BruceWayne - I get a type mismatch for                                                   dt = Cells(i, 7).Value

Comment: What does the data in column G look like? Are there dates *and* other info?

Comment: @BruceWayne - dates and blanks, that's all. it designates a termination date or if there is no date the employee is still active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is you're checking the "A" column for your date info, and deleting based on that. If your dates are in "G", you should check `Cells(x,7)`, not `Cells(x,1)`.

```
Sub DateSelectandClean()
'
' DateSelectandClean Macro
' User enters date and spreadsheet deletes everything prior to that date, ignoring empty cells.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim W2Year As Date, lastRow As Long, i As Long, dateCol As Long
Dim dt      As Date

dateCol = 7                  ' for column G

Do While W2Year = "00:00:00"
    W2Year = Format(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter W2 Year as xx/xx/xxxx Date:", Type:=2), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    MsgBox W2Year
Loop

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, dateCol).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    'If Cells(i, dateCol).Value <> "" Then
    If IsDate(Cells(i,dateCol)) Then
        dt = CDate(Format(Cells(i, dateCol).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
        If dt <= W2Year Then
            Cells(i, dateCol).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I also change the variables from `Date` to `String` which allows a little bit of error catching when the user inputs info.  You can edit that back if you wish, I was just thinking of a time when someone puts in "wrong" or incorrectly formatted info.

Comment: This seems to be getting closer. Run as is it keeps all the dates in column G prior to the entered date. if I change the IF statement to "If (Cells(i, dateCol).Value <> "" And dt > W2Year) Then..." it keeps all the blanks and nothing else.

Comment: @tweeks - Check my edit.  It should work as you asked - deletes any row with a Date in Column G that's before the date entered by the user. It ignores blank cells too.

Comment: I've tried the edit a few times and it gives me the same results as my previous comment. I'm on Excel 2010 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @tweeks - "Run as is it keeps all the dates in column G prior to the entered date." - Yes, isn't that what you wanted?  Or do you also want to remove any blank cell row?

Comment: No I need it to delete the rows with dates prior to the entered date. If they enter 8-1-2007 all rows with that date and before should be deleted. Any dates after the entered date as well as all blanks should remain. When I run the code above for 01-01-2008 I am left with dates ranging from 2005 - 2015 and all the blank spaces are deleted.

Comment: @tweeks hmmm that's odd. Can you post some sample data in to your OP? That way we can see what your data looks like

Comment: I'll need to change the data before uploading it but yes I will do that. I'll let you know when it's done.

Comment: I added an image "Sample Data", I hope that will work. I'm new to this sight so I'm not sure if that is what you were looking for. If you need something different let me know.

Comment: @tweeks - thanks! I've updated the code, it should work for you now.

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error 13 type mismatch on "dt = CDate(Format(Cells(i, dateCol).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"))" now. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @tweeks - Hmm...when that happens, and you click "Debug", what row are you on (what's the value of `i`, hover the mouse over it)? I don't seem to get that error.

Comment: its 46, which is the very last row. It is a blank row so I deleted it and ran the macro again. This time it stops on 42 which is the next blank cell in the column. It appears that it is failing on blank cells.

Comment: @tweeks - When it gets to 42, is that a truly blank cell? Or is there maybe a space in there? It should be skipping over blank cells...

Comment: It is coming from a .CSV file so there could be data in it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but csv files will sometimes have a "," in a field that looks blank. So going along with that thinking I added    " If Cells(i, dateCol).Value <> "" Or Cells(i, dateCol).Value <> "," Then "    But I still get the error on row 46 (the first blank cell)

Comment: @tweeks - Try changing the `or` to `and`.

Comment: I still get the same error in the same place. One other thing, when I put my cursor on "dt" it says "dt = 12:00:00 AM". Shouldn't dt = a date? specifically the date that is in the cell it is looking at in column G?

Comment: Would it be easier to have it look at the cell and ignore it if it is anything except a date?

Comment: @tweeks - Sure, check the edit. I just changed the `IF` to `If IsDate(Cells(i,dateCol)) Then`

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be getting an issue in blank date.
I separate the `IF` so that it won't continue the validation on date.
e.g. `IF "" < #01/01/2017#`

Try this, not much changes though:

```
Sub DateSelectandClean()

' DateSelectandClean Macro
' User enters date and spreadsheet deletes everything prior to that date, ignoring empty cells.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim dateCol, iRow
    Dim W2Year As Date, N As Long
    Dim dt As String

    W2Year = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter W2 Year as dd/mm/yyyy Date:", Type:=2))
    MsgBox W2Year

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    dateCol = 7
    For iRow = N To 2 Step -1
        dt = Cells(iRow, dateCol).Value
        If (Cells(iRow, dateCol).Value <> "") Then
            If (CDate(dt) < CDate(W2Year)) Then
                Cells(iRow, dateCol).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a run-time error '1004' at dt = Cells(iRow, dateCol).Value

Comment: are you using Excel 2016? mine is working as expected.

Comment: I get a type mismatch at "Cells(iRow, dateCol).EntireRow.Delete" now

Comment: try replacing it with "Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete"